# Mi login me lleva al mismo index independientemente el rol en PHP

Tags: php, mysql, php7

Hola estoy haciendo un login en php con roles pero cuando ingreso con diferente rol siempre me redirecciona al mismo index, un rol es de administrador y otro de vendedor incluso cuando le doy al boton sin haber puesto ningun usuario o contraseña me manda al index. Tambien me gustaria saber como crear un sesion para que un rol no pueda entrar a la pagina de otro rol

Aqui esta mi codigo

login.php

```
<section class="login-block">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 login-sec">
            <h2 class="text-center">Iniciar Sesión</h2>

<form action="process_login.php" method="POST">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="text-uppercase">Usuario</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="usuario" placeholder="">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="text-uppercase">Contraseña</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="contraseña" placeholder="">
  </div>

  <div class="form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label">
      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">
      <small>Recordarme</small>
    </label>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-login float-right" name="btn_entrar">Entrar</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Y mi codigo en php

```
<?php
include 'db.php';

if(isset($_POST['btn_entrar']))
{
    $user=$_POST['usuario'];
    $password=$_POST['contraseña']; 
    $admin='Administrador';
    $vendedor='Vendedor';

    $query_admin = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM empleado WHERE usuario='$user' 
              AND contraseña='$password' AND cargo='$admin'") or die($mysqli->error());


    $query_ven = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM empleado WHERE usuario='$user' 
              AND contraseña='$password' AND cargo='$vendedor'") or die($mysqli->error());

    if(count($query_admin)==1)
    {
        header("location: index.php");
    }
    else if(count($query_ven)==1)
    {
        header("location: index_empleados.php");
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<script>alert('Usuario o contraseña son incorrectos')</script>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Alguien podra darte una respuesta mas fina, pero $query_admin devolvio true, y count intenta contar eso y al no poder contarlo devuelve uno. En la documentacion esta todo eso. Creo que no es esta la logica que queres implementar

Comment: Gracias ya lo resolvi en la parte del if le puse mysqli_num_rows:
if(mysqli_num_rows($query_admin)==1)
Y ahora ya me redirecciona a cada index respectivo

Comment: Perfecto!! agrega una respuesta, o eliminemos la pregunta ;)